# Parameter specified as non-null is null - loading Image in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, picasso, nullable, illegalargumentexception

I'm using Picassos Target to load a image from the Internet and generate a Color Palette out of it. When the image doesn't exist anymore, I get the following crash with the Error in the Logcat:

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter placeHolderDrawable
        at .ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3260)
        at .ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3396)
        at .servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at .servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at .servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at .ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2009)
        at .Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at .Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at .ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7319)
        at .reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at .os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at .os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:934)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter placeHolderDrawable
        at .LoadImage$onCreate$1.onPrepareLoad(Unknown Source:2)
        at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:559)
        at .LoadImage.onCreate(LoadImage.kt:154)
        **at .LoadImage.onCreate(LoadImage.kt:154)**
```

Ok, I understand what's going on - Picasso loads the image, the image is null and therefore the app crashes. But how can I handle this problem with a line of code?

This is the section where the problem happens, I marked line 154 for you:

```
    Picasso.get()
            .load(eventimgurl)
            **.into(object : com.squareup.picasso.Target {**
                override fun onBitmapLoaded(bitmap: Bitmap, from: Picasso.LoadedFrom) {
                    assert(iconImg != null)
                    iconImg!!.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
                    Palette.from(bitmap)
                            .generate(Palette.PaletteAsyncListener { palette ->
                                val dividerswatch_dom = palette!!.dominantSwatch
                                val dividerswatch_sub = palette.lightVibrantSwatch

                                if (dividerswatch_dom == null || dividerswatch_sub == null) {

                                    return@PaletteAsyncListener
                                }


                                val gd = GradientDrawable(
                                        GradientDrawable.Orientation.LEFT_RIGHT,
                                        intArrayOf(dividerswatch_dom.rgb, dividerswatch_sub.rgb))
                                gd.cornerRadius = 0f
                                gd.gradientType = GradientDrawable.RADIAL_GRADIENT
                                gd.gradientRadius = 700.0f


                                eventdividerheader.background = gd
                                eventdividerdjstart.background = gd
                                eventdivider_detail_top.background = gd
                                eventdivider_detail_bottom.background = gd

                            })
                }

                override fun onBitmapFailed(e: Exception, errorDrawable: Drawable) {

                }

                override fun onPrepareLoad(placeHolderDrawable: Drawable) {

                }
            })
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, the problem is that library code is not fully compatible with Kotlin. Or in fact, it's more about the IDE you use than the library.

Why?

```
interface Target {
    void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from)
    void onBitmapFailed(Exception e, Drawable errorDrawable)
    void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable)
}
```

The interface above would be the java interface of Target.
As there are no null-annotations using this in Kotlin code can be quite tricky, because we don't know if the type of `placeHolderDrawable` (and other variables) is nullable or not.

So, the kotlin implementation of this interface would be following:

```
object : Target {
    // ...
    override fun onPrepareLoad(placeHolderDrawable: Drawable) {
    }
}
```

or...

```
object : Target {
    // ...
    override fun onPrepareLoad(placeHolderDrawable: Drawable?) {
    }
}
```

And here we are.
When Kotlin compiles to Java byte code it adds `not-null checks` for `not-null types`:

```
kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(param)
```

So, to make your code work... just change `Drawable` to `Drawable?`. Then, there will be no `Intrinsics` call and there will be no exception.

So, even if your method is empty compiler adds `Intrinsics` checks for all not null parameters at the beginning of the method. Feel free to decompile your code and find those calls in empty methods :)

**Conclusion**
The problem is that code without `nullability annotations` is not properly generated by IDE, as types are converted to nonnull types instead of nullable.

Comment: that's one hell of an answer, thank you for getting this clear. I really thought that the library code nowadays is 100% compatible with Kotlin, but it doesn't seem to be like that. Thank you sir :)!

Answer (score 0):

check the condition before loading image like this

```
if (isNullOrEmpty(eventimgurl)) {
        // display default image
    }
    else {
        // load you image from url that is eventimgurl
    Picasso.with(YourActivity::this)
   .load(eventimgurl)
   .into(imgView, object: com.squareup.picasso.Callback {
                override fun onSuccess() {
                    // done
                }
                override fun onError() {
                    // load default image or do something
                }
            })
    }
```

Comment: that's clear, but eventimgurl isn't null in any case, the link is just broke so Picasso tries to connect to the given url (which again isn't null) and than doesn't load the picture